# The dependency ''mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,...' was not found

Tags: xamarin.ios, sharpziplib, mscorlib

i get the following error by compiling my project:

> warning MT3005: The dependency 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' of the assembly
>   'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib, Version=0.86.0.518, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' was not found. Please review the project's
>   references.
>
> warning MT3005: The dependency 'System, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' of the assembly
>   'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib, Version=0.86.0.518, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' was not found. Please review the project's
>   references.
>
> warning MT3006: Could not compute a complete dependency map for the
>   project. This will result in slower build times because Xamarin.iOS
>   can't properly detect what needs to be rebuilt (and what does not need
>   to be rebuilt). Please review previous warnings for more details.

I've found out that the System dependency of my project uses the version 2.0.5.0 and the ZipSharp uses 2.0.0.0

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the warnings you need to get (or build from sources) a version of `ZipSharp` that is compiled against the BCL (mscorlib.dll, System.dll) that is shipped with Xamarin.iOS (i.e. 2.0.5.0).

Note that those are **warnings**, not errors, so it might work.